# Using Binance API Results

Tags: cryptocurrency, binance

I've recently started making calls to Binance API, specifically this:
https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTCBUSD

This call only seems to have 1 parameter (symbol). My question concerns the meaning of the returned fields, or how to interpret them.

Here is a sample of returned data from the above call.

```
{
"symbol": "BTCBUSD",
"priceChange": "1519.63000000",
"priceChangePercent": "3.308",
"weightedAvgPrice": "47059.10006256",
"prevClosePrice": "45935.14000000",
"lastPrice": "47454.77000000",
"lastQty": "0.08014400",
"bidPrice": "47454.76000000",
"bidQty": "0.00858100",
"askPrice": "47454.77000000",
"askQty": "0.22488900",
"openPrice": "45935.14000000",
"highPrice": "48444.00000000",
"lowPrice": "45044.05000000",
"volume": "18094.48897600",
"quoteVolume": "851510367.30253731",
"openTime": 1614347997320,
"closeTime": 1614434397320,
"firstId": 116330237,
"lastId": 117165845,
"count": 835609
```

}

What does **openPrice** and **prevClosePrice** actually mean? They change between each call.

How does **priceChange** and **priceChangePercent** work? What fields are these values calculated from? And why are they markedly different to what I see when viewing Binance site for BTC/BUSD 24 HR period at the same time as I make the call?

Can anyone shed some light on these figures? I've searched online but not been able to find anything descriptive.

When I calculate the price change percent based on the difference between **lastPrice** and **openPrice** I get the following result which does match the **priceChangePercent** value.

((47454.77 - 45935.14) / 45935.14) * 100 = 3.308

Answer (score 0):

openPrice = last candle started at this price

prevClosePrice = last 2nd candle closed at this price (it must be same with next candles open price)

priceChange = difference between start of the day price and current price (start of the day 00.00 in UTC i guess)

priceChangePercent = same with priceChange but percentage (also you can see in binance symbol lists these things, just order by change)

Comment: also you can check [link](https://www.coindesk.com/crypto-trading-101-beginners-guide-candlesticks), Anatomy of candlestick part to understand candles.